# pip install, How to fix ImportError

Tags: python, shell, command-line, command

I'm having `ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing'` error message when I try to use `pip install`. Anyone can help?

Comment: Which Python version do you use? typing.Literal is available from Python 3.8.

Comment: Hi, welcome. It is probably versions of your python and pip are out of date. You will probably need to update it to Python 3.8 or higher as @balrundev stated.

Comment: I'm using 3.9.0

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: yes, 2.7, 3.8.0, and 3.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the configuration of your environmental variables. The first thing, I'd suggest you do is uninstall all the unused versions of python. To my mind, the latest of python 3.x.x series is the best.

**Steps:**

The easiest way of accessing it is just to type `environment variable` in Windows 10 search bar. (Assuming you are using Windows 10)

[image]

Then follow these:

[image]

At the bottom half part of the subsequent window search for `path`:

[image]

If you double click that, look for python. Make sure you have such paths added there and you need to have a compatible version of python. Usually, your python bin directory is located in Program Files.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb.  I really had python 2.7 for one, and 3.9 for other thing. Thank you